# Convert a boolean function into K-map

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I would like to know how can I convert the following boolean function into a truth table and accordingly construct the k-map

$$F = A'B'C'+B'CD'+A'BCD'+AB'C'$$

thanks in advance :)

Comment: thanks @ucoskun for the edit

Comment: Do you really want to write the truth table? It'd be tedious with $2^4 = 16$ rows.

Comment: @Grid can I construct the k-map of this boolean function without the truth table?

Comment: I'd make the truth table as follows: have columns for A,B,C, & D first going 8T8F, 4T4F4T4F, 2T2F..., 1T1F..., and then four columns for A',B',C',D' (this is so your work is organized). Then do each of the four min terms, then you have a column for (A'B'C' + B'CD') and (A'BCD' + AB'C'), finally the last column is F. In total we're talking 16 rows and 15 columns, that's 16 * 15 = 240 terms.

Comment: I don't know of a way to construct a karnaugh map without using a truth table. Though I only learned them briefly in a hardware CS class and not a proper math class. Maybe it's not so bad, since the first 8 columns are pretty quick. Also you may get more helpful responses in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ , since it's a digital logic problem.

Comment: @Grid Thanks mister... much appreciated :)

Comment: You also probably want to use 0's and 1's instead of False and True's. Wikipedia goes through a good example in the case of 4 inputs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip making the truth table (or maybe better said) you can make the truthtable directly in the Karnaugh map. espacially now the formula is in Disjunctive normal form (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form )

For formulas in Disjunctive normal form , you can just plop T(rues) where the products are true

so if you make the karnough map as:

```
     A' A' A  A
     B' B  B  B
C'D' .  .  .  .
C'D  .  .  .  .
C D  .  .  .  .
C D' .  .  .  .
```

Then  for A'B'C' add T's where A'B'C' is true.

```
     A' A' A  A
     B' B  B  B'
C'D' T  .  .  .
C'D  T  .  .  .
C D  .  .  .  .
C D' .  .  .  .
```

Do the same for the other formulas.

Then to end , replace all remailing "." with "F"

DONE

GOOD LUCK

Comment: Thanks mister... much appreciated :)